# Image slider's next button doesn't work. [JQUERY]

Tags: jquery, html

Left button works correctly but when I click right button, all items fadeout and nothing fadein. How can i solve my problem?

JQUERY

```
var LastItem = $("ul#rew > li:last-child").index();
var FirstItem = $("ul#rew > li:first-child").index();
$(".gallery_items i#sag").click(function() {
    $("ul#rew > li").children("img").hide();
    index++;
    if(index == LastItem) { index = FirstItem; }
    $("ul#rew > li").eq(index).children("img").fadeIn(300);
});

$(".gallery_items i#sol").click(function() {
    $("ul#rew > li").children("img").hide();
    index--;
    $("ul#rew > li").eq(index).children("img").fadeIn(300);
    if(index==FirstItem) {index=LastItem;}
});
```

HTML

```
<ul id="rew" class="gallery_content">

    <li>
        <div class="gallery_image" style="background-image:url(IMG/gallery/thumb/rew2010_1.jpg);"><span>2010</span></div>
        <img src="IMG/gallery/rew2010_1.jpg" alt="REW" style="display: none;">
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="gallery_image" style="background-image:url(IMG/gallery/thumb/rew2010_2.jpg);"><span>2010</span></div>
        <img src="IMG/gallery/rew2010_2.jpg" alt="REW" style="display: none;">
    </li>

    ...................

</ul>
```

Comment: checkout the index, LastItem and FirstItem value everytime, you can get the result ownself.

Comment: There are 12 li items. I get 0 from FirstItem and 11 from LastItem. I tried alert(index); , like you said. I got the correct index but stil somethings is wrong.

Comment: can you please make a fiddle??

Comment: I made one for but It doesn't work correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/tjt2c4ca

Comment: I don't find any button to click for left or right.

Comment: Edited code, http://jsfiddle.net/tjt2c4ca/3

Comment: I don't If i can share website or not but you can checkout example here http://akademicevre.com/resimgalerisi

Comment: okey, Let me check

Comment: I see FirstItem and LastItem are defined inside the scope of a function but then you try to use them outside. As a consequence the variables are undefined. Had you tried to define the variables outside?

Comment: @MustafaSöylemez, I did it. Check out the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var index;
        var LastItem;
        var FirstItem;

        $("ul#rew > li").click(function() {
            $("ul#rew > li > img").hide();
            $(this).children("img").fadeIn(300);
            $("#gallery_image_background").fadeIn(300);
            $(".gallery_items > i").fadeIn(300);
            index = $(this).index();
            LastItem = $("ul#rew > li:last-child").index();
            FirstItem = $("ul#rew > li:first-child").index();
        });
```